# SSAS: Error Viewing Cube in Browser

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ssas

When I go to browse a cube I created in SSAS, I am getting this error:

### TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio

Unable to get the window handle for the 'ActionsAwarePivotTable' control. Windowless ActiveX controls are not supported.

Anybody know why and how I can fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you happen to have Lotus Notes running on your machine, by any chance? If so, close Notes and then try again. We hit exactly this problem in our environment.

Comment: Wow, never would have thought that.  Thanks!